# List not modified but error : Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I have below variables

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectedGroups { get; set; }
Dictionary<string,string> grpsList;
```

Below is my iteration

```
if(condition)
 viemodel.SelectedGroups = selectlist1;
else
  viemodel.SelectedGroups = selectlist2;

foreach (var item in viemodel.SelectedGroups) <<--Error message
       grpsList.Remove(item.Value);
```

I am not modifying selectedgroups but using it as a reference to remove from grpsList but its failing in foreach declaration.

---

**Added code**, 
selectlist1 contains reference to grpsList, something like this (removed additional joins and all other code)

```
from g in grpsList
select g).ToSelectList(g => g.Value, g => g.Key);
```

selectlist2 is different list.

Comment: Can you show the implementation of `SelectedGroups`?

Comment: What are `selectlist1` and `selectlist2`?

Comment: This question has been asked many times here

Comment: I am sorry, my mistake. I know it appears several times, as mentioned in the question,  I didn't see the reference as the selectlist1 was having so many joins. Both answers helped me. Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely `SelectedGroups` point to a linq expression that involves `grpsList`.
To avoid this problem do a `.ToList()` before the assigment to `SelectedGroups`. (You can still keep the property signature as `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`)

Using your added code:

```
from g in grpsList
select g).ToSelectList(g => g.Value, g => g.Key).ToList(); <-- here
```

Note that if you do not do the `ToList()` on a linq expression than every time you iterate the Enumerator the complete linq statement is evaluated. This can cause a lot of unnecessary performance issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with

```
foreach (var item in viemodel.SelectedGroups.ToList<SelectListItem>()) 
{
       grpsList.Remove(item.Value);
}
```